# convert mongodb collection to panda dataframe

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

I have mongodb collection the indicate each user movie rates:

```
[
 {
    "movie_rate" : [ 
        {
            "rate" : 4,
            "movie_id" : "608"
        }, 
        {
            "rate" : 4,
            "movie_id" : "1246"
        }
    ]
 },
 {
    "movie_rate" : [ 
        {
            "rate" : 5,
            "movie_id" : "1136"
        }, 
        {
            "rate" : 4,
            "movie_id" : "2081"
        }
    ]
 },
 {
    "movie_rate" : [ 
        {
            "rate" : 5,
            "movie_id" : "2947"
        }, 
        {
            "rate" : 5,
            "movie_id" : "1240"
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

And I have list of 'movie_id' for data frame columns. now I want to create pandas data frame like below picture, the value of each cell is actually the rate of the movie and each row belong to one user data the empty cell indicates, that user do not rate that movie
[image]

How can generate this data frame in most efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Given the data you provided stored in a variable called `data` and assuming that the user ids are given by the index of the rating in the `data` array, you can do the following steps:

First transform the data in a matrix shape

```
df = pd.concat(map(lambda x: DataFrame(x[1]['movie_rate'], index=np.repeat(x[0], 2)), enumerate(data)))
df.index.name = 'user'
df

     movie_id   rate
user
0    608        4
0    1246       4
1    1136       5
1    2081       4
2    2947       5
2    1240       5
```

Then use the [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) method to where the values should be the ratings, the columns should be the movie ids and the row index defines the user ids.

```
df.pivot_table('rate', columns='movie_id', index=df.index)

movie_id    1136    1240    1246    2081    2947    608
user                        
0           NaN     NaN     4.0     NaN     NaN     4.0
1           5.0     NaN     NaN     4.0     NaN     NaN
2           NaN     5.0     NaN     NaN     5.0     NaN
```